# memory clobbered before allocated block

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, memory-management

After a few days of painful debugging, I could reproduce a bug in one of my unit test with this small program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <new>

int main(){
    try{
        for(size_t j=0;j<100;++j){
            std::cout<<j<<std::endl;
            std::mutex mutex;
            std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable>cv;
            std::vector<std::thread>v(10);
            auto wait=[&](size_t i){
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex>ul(mutex);
                if(!cv){cv=std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>();}
                cv->wait_for(ul,std::chrono::milliseconds(i*10));
            };
            for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i){v[i]=std::thread(wait,i);}
            for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i){v[i].join();}}}
    catch(...){
        std::cout<<"Exception"<<std::endl;
        std::abort();}
}
```

When I compile with lmcheck on:

```
g++-4.9.2 -lmcheck -std=c++1y -pthread /home/Arnaud/Test.cpp -o Test
```

the program runs and stops with `memory clobbered before allocated block`

I could reproduce this on multiple machines and both with gcc 4.9.2 and gcc 5.1. **What is wrong with this code?**

NB: This code runs fine with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I guess it's because `mcheck` isn't thread-safe: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html

Comment: Yup, it's not thread safe.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Thanks. You should write a small answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html), `mcheck` isn't thread-safe.

It looks like linking with `-lmcheck` adds allocation hooks which call `mcheck`, meaning that it's no longer safe to allocate and deallocate memory from multiple threads without extra synchronisation.

Comment: I just spent hours in gdb and dump core stack traces searching for clues about what mcheck() found wrong in my code. And it was just using threads. :( You saved my day stating the obviously documented. I did read the man page without noticing it ! :(