# Program hangs in Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

Some background: I am trying to track a bug which is causing me major headaches. After many dead ends (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894916/memory-clobbered-before-allocated-block)) I finally ended up with this code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SRWLOCK srwl;
    InitializeSRWLock(&srwl);
    for(size_t i=0;i<1000;++i)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread>threads;
        for(size_t j=0;j<100;++j)
        {
            OutputDebugString(".");
            threads.emplace_back([&](){
                AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&srwl);
                //Code below modifies the probability to see the bug.
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
                std::wstringstream wss;
                wss<<std::this_thread::get_id();
                wss.str();
                //Code above modifies the probability to see the bug.
                ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&srwl);});
        }
        for(auto&t:threads){t.join();}
        OutputDebugString((std::to_string(i)+"\n").data());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code inside VS 2013 debugger the program hangs with an output like this one:

```
....................................................................................................0
....................................................................................................1
....................................................................................................2
...........................
```

Strangely enough, If I pause the debugger and inspect what is going on, one of the threads is inside AcquireSRWLockExclusive (in NtWaitForAlertByThreadId) apparently there is no reason why the program is hanging. When I click resume, the program happily continues and print some more stuff until it is blocked again.

**Do you have any Idea what is going on here ?**

Some more info:

- As far as I can tell, this bug only exists on Windows 8.1.
- I tried VS2013.4 and VS2015 RC.
- I could reproduce it on two different computers under Windows 8.1.
- One of the machine was formatted, the RAM, CPU and Disk tested (I thought of a malfunction because at first I could only observe the bug on this particular machine)
- I could never reproduce it on Windows 7.
- It may be useful to modify the code between the comments to observe the bug. When I added the microsecond sleep, I could at last reproduce the bug on another computer.
- With VS2015 RC I could reproduce the same behavior with a simple std::mutex. On VS2013 however the SRWLOCK seems mandatory to observe the bug.

Comment: Could be you are in a deadlock and once you enter the debugger it changes the synchronization and the deadlock disappears.

Comment: @NathanOliver How could this be possible? There is only one mutex in the code.

Comment: Does the program ever hang when run outside the debugger?

Comment: @RetiredNinja It does not hang outside of the debugger.

Comment: Painful to watch.  std::thread is built on top of the concurrency time.  In for a penny, in for a pound, use `Concurrency::reader_writer_lock` from `<ppl.h>` instead.  That's probably a deal-breaker, do consider calling Microsoft Support about this.

Comment: @HansPassant I submitted a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1327211) to Microsoft. I will also look into your ppl suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by an OS scheduler bug introduced in the spring 2014 update to Windows 8.1. A hotfix for this problem was released in May 2015 and available at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3036169.

Comment: I tried the hotfix and it solves the issue. It seems a lot more slower though.

Answer (score 1):

For me it looks like a bug in windows OS, I have different code variants that hangs using new Vista primitives under debugger in Win 8.1 / Server 2012R2 after April 2014 update. Also some thread pool wait function hangs too. Looks like it mostly tied to other thread finished execution at the moment of wait/lock. Here is the simple code that always hangs under debugger in NtWaitForAlertByThreadId() :

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#pragma optimize("",off)
VOID CALLBACK _WorkCallback(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE Instance, PVOID pUser, PTP_WORK Work)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX / 256; i++) {}
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < INT_MAX / 256; i++) {}
    return 0;
}
#pragma optimize("",on)

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    LONGLONG c = 0;

    while(!_kbhit())
    {
        PTP_WORK ptpw = CreateThreadpoolWork(&_WorkCallback, NULL, NULL);
        if (ptpw != NULL) 
        {
            for(long i = 0; i < 3; i++) SubmitThreadpoolWork(ptpw);

            CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);

            WaitForThreadpoolWorkCallbacks(ptpw, FALSE);
            CloseThreadpoolWork(ptpw);
        }

        printf("%I64d                                 \r", c++);
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I have no idea where to report it to the Microsoft.

Comment: I could reproduce the hanging on my system too.